# Catch Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND using winston

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I've been using winston to push logs to [logmatic](http://logmatic.io) for almost a year, and this week I had to turn it off because I get random connection errors which crash the production server. I turned it off as a temporal fix, but I would prefer something like a try/catch, which I tried but didn't work.

Here's my current code:

```
const Winston = require('winston')
require('winston-logstash')

const transports = []
transports.push(new Winston.transports.Console({
  level: 'debug',
  colorize: true,
  prettyPrint: true
}))

try {
  transports.push(new (Winston.transports.Logstash)({
    level: 'info',
    port: 10514,
    host: 'api.logmatic.asdsadio',
    meta: { logmaticKey: 'Xen03ppdS_Cm24hxbz1_kg' },
    node_name: 'api'
  }))

  const logger = new (Winston.Logger)({
    transports: transports
  })
}
catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}

module.exports = logger
```

Comment: Why you need try/catch if you turned it off?

Comment: And try/catch should be set not to transports initialization, but to each calling `logger.<level>()` call. But it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @alexmac so I can safely turn it on, the code I shared is using the service. That's my local environment, in production it's turned off

Comment: If `logmatic` doesn't work, disable it and on local environment. Just comment this code with transport or set `silent: false`.

Comment: @alexmac but it's also crashing on the production server (aws)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
const methods = ['info', 'warn', 'error'];
methods.forEach(method => {
    logger[method] = new Proxy(logger[method], {
        apply: function(target, thisArg, args) {
            try {
                target.call(logger, ...args);
            } catch(error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        },
    });
});
```

just after initializing your logger while you're figuring out why you get connections error. At least, it should prevent crashes. It will basically intercepts each call to **logger.info**, **logger.warn**, **logger.error** and wrap them around a try catch.

Comment: I'll assume it works, since there's been no more crashes. Thanks!